# What is the code to use your own data instead of the random data that is generated here?

Tags: d3.js, nvd3.js

I'm trying to build the example here http://nvd3.org/ghpages/scatter.html
but a customized modified version using my own data. I'm having trouble building a code that uses real data, could anyone show me with an example code of what a possible code would look like? either referencing inline data or on a CSV would be fine.

I'm just having excessive difficulte trying to figure out how to back out from the randomData function.

my example page is here http://goo.gl/XHela and the code i have is....

```
<div id="offsetDiv">
  <div id="test1" class="chartWrap">
    <svg></svg>
  </div>
</div>

<script>
//Format A
var chart;

nv.addGraph(function() {
  chart = nv.models.scatterChart()
                .showDistX(true)
                .showDistY(true)
                //.height(500)
                .useVoronoi(true)
                .color(d3.scale.category10().range());

  chart.xAxis.tickFormat(d3.format('.02f'))
  chart.yAxis.tickFormat(d3.format('.02f'))

  d3.select('#test1 svg')
      .datum(randomData(4,40))
    .transition().duration(500)
      .call(chart);

  nv.utils.windowResize(chart.update);

  chart.dispatch.on('stateChange', function(e) { nv.log('New State:', JSON.stringify(e)); });

  return chart;
});


function randomData(groups, points) { //# groups,# points per group
  var data = [],
      shapes = ['circle', 'cross', 'triangle-up', 'triangle-down', 'diamond', 'square'],
      random = d3.random.normal();

  for (i = 0; i < groups; i++) {
    data.push({
      key: 'Group ' + i,
      values: []
    });

    for (j = 0; j < points; j++) {
      data[i].values.push({
        x: random(), 
        y: random()
        , //size: Math.random()
   //     shape: shapes[j % 6]
      });
    }
  }

  return data;
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `randomData` function returns a structure like this:

```
var data = [{key: 'Group1', values: [{x: 1, y: 1}, {x: 2, y: 3}, {x: 4, y: 9}]},
            {key: 'Group2', values: [{x: 32, y: 0}, {x: 3, y: 54}, {x: 1, y: 8}]}];
```

So basically you have a key and a list of values, each consisting of an object with `x` and `y` members. You should be able to use the code above as a drop-in replacement for a call to `randomData` and any data you have can be used by converting it into this format.